# Where is the implementation of the compareTo?

Tags: java

Below is the class that implements the `Comparator` interface.

```
public class Descending implements Comparator {

  @Override
  public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if( o1 instanceof Comparable && o2 instanceof Comparable) {
      Comparable c1 = (Comparable) o1;
      Comparable c2 = (Comparable) o2;
      return c1.compareTo(c2);
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

As you can see, two integer values are compared and  will be sorted. What I am wondering is that in the compare overriding method, it use `Comparable` interface for comparing two values as `c2.compareTo(c1)`. I think that `Comparable` is also the interface so there must be detailed implementation of the `compareTo` method for comparing two integers.
However, when I go into the `compareTo` method, it is just the inside of the `Comparable` interface. I was trying to look for the location of the implementation of the `compareTo` based on the assumption (`compareTo` in the `Comparable` method should be overrided somewhere to execute `c2.compareTo(c1)`) but failed to search it and I think that there is no place to define its overriding method. Is my assumption false?

Comment: Um, `Integer.compareTo` in this case? It's not really clear to me what you're asking, otherwise...

Comment: This doesn't make sense: the only way in which `o1` and `o2` are not instances of `Comparable` is if at least one of them is null. In that case, you don't want to always return -1: if you want to handle nulls, you need to return a value depending on whether they are both null, only the first is null, or only the second is null. Alternatively, don't handle nulls, and throw a `NullPointerException` (for example).

Comment: Also: `Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder().reversed()` is easier (if you don't want to handle nulls).

Comment: Or even: `Comparator.reverseOrder()`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I changed the `Integer` to `Comparable`. What I am asking is that `compareTo` method has its own detailed implementation logic not just declaration in the interface. but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @sclee1: Well it's "whatever the implementation is based on the actual type of the object that `o1` refers to". Do you understand that at some point, there will be a concrete type involved? There's no such thing as an object which is *only* an instance of an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concrete class of `Object o1` & `Object o2` implements the `compareTo` method.

Take for example the `Instant` class. The [Javadoc for that class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) says `implements Comparable<Instant>`. That means the author of this class promises to implement the methods of that interface `Comparable`. The only method on that interface is `compareTo`.

So we scroll down the page of `Instant` Javadoc to find a method [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#compareTo(java.time.Instant)) that takes an argument of type `Instant`.

If you look at the open-source implementation of that class from the OpenJDK project you’ll find the [source code of that `java.time.Instant#compareTo` method](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/Instant.java).